# Доступ к apache из локальной сети

Tags: ubuntu, apache, сеть, apache2, localhost

Имеется Ubuntu 14.04 + Apache2(+ PHP + mysql...). Сайт находится в var/www/. При подключении по localhost или 127.0.0.1 всё работает, если в адресной строке ввожу ip (допустим 150.147.146.150) всё работает. Как только сажусь за любой пк в сети (допустим 150.147.146.149) и пытаюсь в адресной строке браузера прописать 150.147.146.150 или 150.147.146.150:80 не получаю страничку, а только ошибку.

Как настроить apache2 для доступа к страничкам извне. Меня интересует доступ к localhost машины с apache извне? Все пк находятся в одной сети и отлично пингуются.

/ect/apache2/apache2.conf

```
ServerName myserver
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
  Allow from all
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen *:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
  Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Файл hosts не менялся

```
127.0.1.1 $fqdn $hostname
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Comment: Приложите еще конфиг виртуальных хостов.

Comment: Уже приложил (000-default.conf)